# What gcode keyword is responsible for "Click to resume" feature?

Tags: g-code, 3d-printing

I want to make a gcode to make it easier to level my ender 3 pro, that uses the marlin firmware. On previous CHEP levelling gcodes, i've seen the "Click to resume" feature that waits for the user to click the knob to move to the other spot. I can not seem to find anything about this on the internet at all. Any of you guys have any idea of how to accomplish this "Click to resume" feature in gcode?

I tried googling about it and i did not seem to find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried M999?

Here:
https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M999.html
I read
"Return the machine to Running state".

If you are inside a loop (e.g.: waiting for a temperature to be reached), M108 can get you out.

https://marlinfw.org/docs/gcode/M108.html